# Using JavaScript how do I insert html code into my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, xhtml

Ok so I am using xhtml not html. I am getting data using a hidden xhtml component sending it to JavaScript. The data is a JSON array. I want to manipulate the data and format it adding xhtml tags and send back to the xhtml page and display it. How do I add the code to the **< ul id="ticker01">** element?

Do I do something like:

```
var ticker01 = document.getElementById("ticker01");
ticker01.innerhtml = "<li><span>[15:38:00]</span><a href="#">Red fish</a></li><li><span>[15:39:00]</span><a href="#">Blue fish</a></li>"
```

Or like so with jQuery:

```
$( "<li><span>[15:38:00]</span><a href="#">Red fish</a></li><li><span>[15:39:00]</span><a href="#">Blue fish</a></li>" ).appendTo( "ticker01" );
```

xhtml page:

```
<h:body>
<h:inputText id="chatMessagesHidden" value="#{chatRoom.msgsAsJson}" style="display: none" />
        <ul id="ticker01">
                <li><span>[15:38:00]</span><a href="#">Red fish</a></li>
                <li><span>[15:39:00]</span><a href="#">Blue fish</a></li>
                <li><span>[15:39:30]</span><a href="#">Old fish</a></li>
                <li><span>[15:39:30]</span><a href="#">New fish</a></li>                    
        </ul>
</h:body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var chatMessages;
var chatMsg;

$(document).ready(function() {
    chatMessages = $('chatMessagesHidden');

    for (var i=0; i < chatMessages.length; i++) {
        chatMsg = chatMessages[i];
    // Manipulate the data to send back to xhtml page
    }                
});
```

Will either of these work or do I have to go up a tag level and insert the whole ul tag in the body??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work but you need to add `#` to target element by `id`:

```
chatMessages = $('.chatMessagesHidden');
```

Also, instead of for loop, you can use `$.each()`

```
$.each($('.chatMessagesHidden'), function(i) {
    chatMsg = chatMessages[i];
    // Manipulate the data to send back to xhtml page
});
```

---

I forgot to mention that `id` is unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<h:inputText class="chatMessagesHidden" value="#{chatRoom.msgsAsJson}" style="display: none" />
```